# How to clone a dojo (TypeScript) project from codesandbox to my server?

Tags: typescript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, codesandbox

I need to migrate/clone a project that is in https://codesandbox.io/s/8zro6m4kj9 is a list in Dojo (I do not know the version), but it is a file with extension .ts (TypeScript).

I tried to download the project and run it, then I tried to install Dojo 5, and finally I try to compile the ts.

In short, days ago I am trying to run this project on my server. In simple words could you explain how I can manage to migrate this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export you project via File > Export as zip. Then unpack it and run `npm install`. When that is ready run `npm install -g @dojo/cli` and `npm i @dojo/cli-build-app` because your project needs to be build by Dojo. This will install the cli for Dojo and all that is needed to build your app.

Run `dojo build` to build the application. You can run `dojo build --mode dev --watch memory --serve` to startup a local development server.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.